# TextTrackList onchange event not working in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-video, microsoft-edge

The `TextTrackList.onchange` event is not working in *IE* and *Edge*. In *Chrome* and *FireFox* it works fine.

Is there any alternative I can use? Ive searched through the available *events* but can't find any.

Or how can I create a workaround? So it works amongst all browsers?

https://www.javascripture.com/TextTrackList

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');

video.textTracks.addEventListener('change', function () {
  console.log("TextTracks change event fired!");
});
```

```css
video {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<video controls id="video">
  <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <track label="Caption #1" kind="subtitles" srclang="nl" src="path/to/caption1.vtt">
  <track label="Caption #2" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="path/to/caption2.vtt">
  <track label="Caption #3" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" src="path/to/caption3.vtt">
</video>
```

Comment: Intresting issue. I have found this one working on the mentioned browsers, but with a different approach. Maybe there is something here for you too. Original URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video    Live Demo: http://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/    GitHubSourceCode: https://github.com/iandevlin/iandevlin.github.io/tree/master/mdn/video-player-with-captions

Comment: The captions are working fine, the problem is not the captions itself. But the JavaScript event handler onchange, when you change a caption, isn't working in IE and Edge.

Comment: The intresting part is that when you do console.log(video.textTracks); before the event. IE has only the event "onaddtrack"; Chrome has add, remove and change. This is probably the issue. Maybe that is not supported and need to be added to that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to create a kind of polyfill.

First to detect if we support the event or not, we can check for `('onchange' in window.TextTrackList)`. So we can integrate our unperfect polyfill conditionally and leave the correct implementations unchanged.

Then, we can iterate every x-time over our TextTrackList's TextTracks in order to find which one is the active one, it should be the one with its `mode` set to `"showing"`.

Now, we just have to store the previous active track and check if the current one is the same. Otherwise, fire the Event.

So a simple implementation could be

```js
// in an outer scope
// textTracks is our TextTrackList object
var active = getActive();

// start polling
poll();

function poll() {
  // schedule next check in a frame
  requestAnimationFrame(poll);
  var current = getActive();

  if (current !== active) {
    active = current; // update the active one
    // dispatchEvent is not supported on TextTrackList in IE...
    onchange({
      target: textTracks
    });
  }
}

function getActive() {
  for (var i = 0; i < textTracks.length; i++) {
    if (textTracks[i].mode === 'showing') {
      return textTracks[i];
    }
  }
}
```

But to implement a better polyfill, we will want to override the original `addEventListener`, `removeEventListener` and `onchange` properties of the TextTrackList prototype.

Here is a rough implementation, which will not take care of the third param of *[add/remove]EventListener*.

```js
(function() {
  /* Tries to implement an 'change' Event on TextTrackList Objects when not implemented */

  if (window.TextTrackList && !('onchange' in window.TextTrackList.prototype)) {
    var textTracksLists = [], // we will store all the TextTrackLists instances
      polling = false; // and run only one polling loop

    var proto = TextTrackList.prototype,

      original_addEvent = proto.addEventListener,
      original_removeEvent = proto.removeEventListener;

    var onchange = {
      get: getonchange,
      set: setonchange
    };

    Object.defineProperty(proto, 'onchange', onchange);
    Object.defineProperty(proto, 'addEventListener', fnGetter(addListener));
    Object.defineProperty(proto, 'removeEventListener', fnGetter(removeListener));

    function fnGetter(fn) {
      return {
        get: function() {
          return fn;
        }
      };
    }


    /*  When we add a new EventListener, we attach a new object on our instance
     This object set as '._fakeevent' will hold informations about
      the current EventListeners
      the current onchange handler
      the parent <video> element if any
      the current activeTrack
    */
    function initFakeEvent(instance) {
      // first try to grab the video element from where we were generated
      // this is useful to not run useless tests when the video is detached
      var vid_elems = document.querySelectorAll('video'),
        vid_elem = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < vid_elems.length; i++) {
        if (vid_elems[i].textTracks === instance) {
          vid_elem = vid_elems[i];
          break;
        }
      }

      textTracksLists.push(instance);
      instance._fakeevent = {
        parentElement: vid_elem,
        listeners: {
          change: []
        }
      }
      if (!polling) { // if we are the first instance being initialised
        polling = true;
        requestAnimationFrame(poll); // start the checks
      }

      return instance._fakeevent;
    }

    function getonchange() {
      var fakeevent = this._fakeevent;
      if (!fakeevent || typeof fakeevent !== 'object') {
        return null;
      }
      return fakeevent.onchange || null;
    }

    function setonchange(fn) {
      var fakeevent = this._fakeevent;
      if (!fakeevent) {
        fakeevent = initFakeEvent(this);
      }
      if (fn === null) fakeevent.onchange = null;
      if (typeof fn !== 'function') return fn;
      return fakeevent.onchange = fn;
    }

    function addListener(type, fn, options) {
      if (type !== 'change') { // we only handle change for now
        return original_addEvent.bind(this)(type, fn, options);
      }
      if (!fn || typeof fn !== 'object' && typeof fn !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('Argument 2 of EventTarget.addEventListener is not an object.');
      }
      var fakeevent = this._fakeevent;
      if (!fakeevent) {
        fakeevent = initFakeEvent(this);
      }
      if (typeof fn === 'object') {
        if (typeof fn.handleEvent === 'function') {
          fn = fn.handleEvent;
        } else return;
      }
      // we don't handle options yet...
      if (fakeevent.listeners[type].indexOf(fn) < 0) {
        fakeevent.listeners[type].push(fn);
      }
    }

    function removeListener(type, fn, options) {
      if (type !== 'change') { // we only handle change for now
        return original_removeEvent.call(this, arguments);
      }
      var fakeevent = this._fakeevent;
      if (!fakeevent || !fn || typeof fn !== 'object' && typeof fn !== 'function') {
        return
      }
      if (typeof fn === 'object') {
        if (typeof fn.handleEvent === 'function') {
          fn = fn.handleEvent;
        } else return;
      }
      // we don't handle options yet...
      var index = fakeevent.listeners[type].indexOf(fn);
      if (index > -1) {
        fakeevent.listeners[type].splice(index, 1);
      }
    }


    function poll() {
      requestAnimationFrame(poll);
      textTracksLists.forEach(check);
    }

    function check(instance) {
      var fakeevent = instance._fakeevent;
      // if the parent vid not in screen, we probably have not changed
      if (fakeevent.parentElement && !fakeevent.parentElement.parentElement) {
        return;
      }
      // get the current active track
      var current = getActiveTrack(instance);
      // has changed
      if (current !== fakeevent.active) {
        if (instance.onchange) {
          try {
            instance.onchange({
              type: 'change',
              target: instance
            });
          } catch (e) {}
        }
        fakeevent.listeners.change.forEach(call, this);
      }
      fakeevent.active = current;
    }

    function getActiveTrack(textTracks) {
      for (var i = 0; i < textTracks.length; i++) {
        if (textTracks[i].mode === 'showing') {
          return textTracks[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    function call(fn) {
      fn({
        type: 'change',
        target: this
      });
    }


  }
})();

var video = document.getElementById('video');

video.textTracks.onchange = function ontrackchange(e) {
  console.log('changed');
};
```

```css
video {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<video controls id="video">
  <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <track label="Caption #1" kind="subtitles" srclang="nl" src="path/to/caption1.vtt">
   <track label="Caption #2" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="path/to/caption2.vtt">
   <track label="Caption #3" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" src="path/to/caption3.vtt">
</video>
```

Comment: I tested on IE11, it doens't work. When changing the caption, the `console.log('changed', e);` isn't fired.

Comment: @Red han... there might be something else they didn't do right... Will delete for now and might come back with a fix once I get time to start my VM

Comment: Seems to work now, let you know if Ive time to test further more. Thanks.

Comment: @Red Alright. And I'll see if I've got time to rewrite it more like a polyfill (with addEventListener & removeEventListener)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that!

Comment: @Red Still not perfect, but I added a better polyfill, which won't require to call an other method, and will start a single poll loop for all TextTracks in the document.

Comment: Works like a charm already, will refine it little more to my needs. Really much thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it is an issue with IE and Edge.
What you can do is listen to an event on the track load. Just pay attention that the track has got to be on the same domain, otherwise, you will get a silent error (CURS) and the event lister will not list the event.

I have created a code pan so you could try it https://codepen.io/shahar-polak/project/live/AnVpEw/

**NOTE:** The code will trigger one event in IE and Edge and two events on Chrome and Firefox. Make sure you check for the client browser before using in production.

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const tracks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('track'));
video.textTracks.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('TextTracks change event fired!');
});
// For IE and Edge
tracks.forEach((track) => {
  track.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log('change track');
  }, false);
})
```

```css
video {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<video controls id="video" >
    <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <track label="Caption #1" kind="subtitles" srclang="nl" src="./en.vtt">
    <track label="Caption #2" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="./en.vtt">
    <track label="Caption #3" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" src="https://iandevlin.com/html5/dynamic-track/captions/sintel-en.vtt">
</video>
```

Comment: I tried to help him also, and tried something similar like this. But like in your case which I just tested it will only trigger the "change" the first time you click a subtitle. So in total there will be 3 change events, you can't have a fourth or fifth.

Comment: @SehaxX I'm sorry, what do you mean? He asked to listen to the change event of the track, and this is exactly what the code does.

Comment: I mean, if you go Caption 1 then to caption 2 and lets say to caption 3 (this works great) but when you then go back to caption 1 or 2 there is no event any more. Or maybe I tested it wrong.

Comment: You are correct, I did not check this option last night.
I'll see tonight what I can do and to find another solution.

Comment: Yeah, it works a little bit. But like @SehaxX said, it doens't really work.